# 2nd conditional real vs imagned

Tags: conditionals

> If  we **didn't** attend that meeting, it would be better.
> If we **don't** attend that meeting, it would be better.

**are these 2nd conditional as real events happened in past?**

Comment: At the moment I think this is off-topic. If you wrote these sentences, then you are asking for them to be checked, which is off-topic. Or, if you found these sentences somewhere else, you haven't showed any research.

Comment: The first one doesn't refer to a past event; it's a recommendation not to attend.

Comment: @KateBunting what about this one, If we don't attend that meeting, It would be better VS If we didn't attend that meeting, It would be better.

Comment: "It would be better if we didn't." "It will be better if we don't."

Comment: If you're asking about a past event, the most natural thing would be *if we **hadn't** attended*, since you already have attended.

Comment: @stangdon, if this is 3rd conditional.
if we hadn't attended the meeting, it would have been better.
what to say for 2nd conditional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, classifying conditionals as "first, second, etc" is not how native speakers discuss them, and in my view is not very useful. Too many valid possibilities are  thus left out of account.

About the given texts:

> - (1) If we didn't attend that meeting, it would be better.
> - (2) If we don't attend that meeting, it would be better.

Neither of these is talking about past events. Sentence (1) is suggesting that we not attend the meeting. Sentence (2) is doing much the same. (1) is probably said with the implication that the decision is already made, or that the speaker is not the decision maker, while (2) is stronger, and might be said by a decision maker or one of a group of decision makers, with the decision still to be made. This is a very fine nuance, and particularly in speech may not always be adhered to.

To speak about past events that might have happened in a different way, one could say:

> (3) If we **hadn't** attended that meeting, it **would have been** better.

Sentence (3) is discussing an unreal past, one that never occurred, although it might have.

All three sentences are grammatically valid, but (3) has a different meaning from (1) or (2).